# datagridview to reportviewer C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I need to transfer data from datagridview to reportviewer. My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;


namespace test
{
     public partial class Form1 : Form
     {

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("test");
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("One");
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("two");
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("three");
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("four");
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("five");
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("six");
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add("test", "test ", "1", "2", "3", "4");
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(980, 10, 70, 20, 50);
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(860, 20, 50, 60, 35);
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(950, 80, 35, 30, 40);
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(800, 40, 90, 30, 25);
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(900, 20, 45, 30, 60);
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(300, 20, 20, 20, 20);
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add("check" , 50, 80, 50, 70);
   }
}
```

These references haven't helped:
[How to Pass data table from DataGridView ro ReportViewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23670958/how-to-pass-data-table-from-datagridview-ro-reportviewer?rq=1)

[Show data from datagridview to reportviewer C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31314032/show-data-from-datagridview-to-reportviewer-c-sharp)
How to show data from datagridview to reportviewer C#?

Comment: You can use a `DataTable` as `DataSource` of your `DataGridView`. Then create a report using the same `DataTable` and set it as `DataSource` of report too.

Comment: I tried so too, the report empty. DataTable table1 = new DataTable();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = table1;
            table1.Columns.Add("test");... DataSet set = new DataSet();
            set.DataSetName = "datasetname";
            set.Tables.Add(table1);

Comment: You're `DataGridView` in above example doesn't use a `DataSource`. You are adding rows directly to the control. Use a `DataTable`.

Comment: You also can use Business Objects. For example take a look at this post: [Feed RDLC (Local) report report from List (Entity FrameWork)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38692746/3110834)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add directly to dataGridView.
Try to add it from a IList.

To add Column

```
DataGridViewColumn columnTime = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                   columnTime .DataPropertyName = "Time";
                   columnTime .Name = "Time:";
dataGridView.Columns.Add(columnTime );
```

Then add it to DataGridView

```
var bindTime= new BindingList<Time>(listTime);
var sourceTime= new BindingSource(bindTime, null);
dataGridView.DataSource = sourceTime;
```

Use the same to ReportViewer, and if you need to add something new to DataGridView, just Add to IList and refresh both DataGrid and ReportViewer
I guess it will be easier than add each line individually